# Nested fragment in dynamic ViewPager attached to wrong parent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` that can display either four or five tabs (toggleable using "DO STUFF" and "DO STUFF2" button). I am using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` for my `ViewPager`.
[image]
For the "Table" tab only, i added a fragment within it using `FragmentTransaction.replace()`.
[image]

However when i toggle to five tabs the nested fragment is added to BOTH "Squad" tab and "Table" tab. I only want it to be added to "Table" tab. How can i accomplish this?
[image]

Fragment holding our ViewPager:

```
public class GrandpaFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private SectionPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;       

    // Some irrelevant codes

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grandpa, container, false);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pagerTournament);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.setViewPager(mViewPager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        btnInfo=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnInfo);
        btnSquad=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSquad);
        btnTable=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTable);
        btnFixtures=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnFixtures);
        btnStats=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnStats);
        layoutMainTab=(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.layoutMainTab);

        // Set onClickListener
        btnInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSquad.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTable.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnFixtures.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnStats.setOnClickListener(this);

        setupTabButtonsText();

        return rootView;
    }

    public void update(){
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.updateAdapterData(5);

        setupTabButtonsText();
    }
    public void update2(){
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.updateAdapterData(4);

        setupTabButtonsText();
    }

    private void setupTabButtonsText(){
        if(mSectionsPagerAdapter.totalTabCount == 4){
            layoutMainTab.setWeightSum(8);
            btnSquad.setText("Table");
            btnTable.setText("Fixture");
            btnFixtures.setText("Stats");
            btnStats.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            layoutMainTab.setWeightSum(10);
            btnSquad.setText("Squad");
            btnTable.setText("Table");
            btnFixtures.setText("Fixture");
            btnStats.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnInfo:
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                break;
            case R.id.btnSquad:
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                break;
            case R.id.btnTable:
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                break;
            case R.id.btnFixtures:
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                break;
            case R.id.btnStats:
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment for each screen in ViewPager:

```
public class PapaFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private Button button, button2;

    public PapaFragment() {
    }

    public static PapaFragment newInstance(String sectionNumber) {
        PapaFragment fragment = new PapaFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_papa, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getString(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dostuff);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dostuff2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        if(getArguments().getString(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER).equals("Table")) {
            SonFragment f = SonFragment.newInstance("A", "B");
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.placeholder, f).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.dostuff){
            ((GrandpaFragment)getParentFragment()).update();
        }
        else{
            ((GrandpaFragment)getParentFragment()).update2();
        }

    }
}
```

Our FragmentStatePagerAdapter:

```
public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private static final int TOTAL_TAB_SQUAD = 5;
    private static final int TOTAL_TAB_NO_SQUAD = 4;

    private Context mContext;
    public int totalTabCount = 4;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private FragmentManager fm;

    public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm = fm;
    }

    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        mViewPager = viewPager;
    }

    public void updateAdapterData(int count){
        totalTabCount = count;

        int currentItem = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentItem);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment=null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = PapaFragment.newInstance("InfoDetail");
                break;
            case 1:
                if(totalTabCount == TOTAL_TAB_SQUAD) {
                    fragment = PapaFragment.newInstance("Squad");
                }
                else {
                    fragment = PapaFragment.newInstance("Table");
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(totalTabCount == TOTAL_TAB_SQUAD) {
                    fragment = PapaFragment.newInstance("Table");
                }
                else {
                    fragment = PapaFragment.newInstance("Fixture");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(totalTabCount == TOTAL_TAB_SQUAD) {
                    fragment = PapaFragment.newInstance("Fixture");
                }
                else {
                    fragment = PapaFragment.newInstance("Stats");
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = PapaFragment.newInstance("Stats");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return totalTabCount;
    }
}
```

Xml for GrandpaFragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTournamentTab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutMainTab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Info" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnSquad"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Squad"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnTable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Table" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnFixtures"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Fixture" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnStats"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Stats"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pagerTournament"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Xml for PapaFragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_below="@id/section_label"
        android:id="@+id/dostuff"
        android:text="do stuff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_below="@id/section_label"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dostuff"
        android:id="@+id/dostuff2"
        android:text="do stuff2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/placeholder"
        android:layout_below="@id/dostuff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```